# data dictionary can be used to retrieve auditing results

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g

I need an example on how to data dictionary can be use for  retrieve auditing results in oracle 11g

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to read about auditing Oracle doc has described it is nice detail. You can refer the below link.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10575/tdpsg_auditing.htm#TDPSG50000

For example you can refer the below blog.

https://ramkedem.com/en/oracle-auditing-examples/